# How to navigate to another webpage if the password is different in Using Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have a webpage called http://z.z.z.z , this link will be common for 10 different clients . Now, what I want is to create 10 different passwords for respective client so that when client hits this URL HTTP authentication box will appear , then client will enter their respective password and it will take them to their respective dashboard . Can someone help me to achieve this . I am done for client 1 with the following default.conf.

```
upstream ki {
        server x.x.x.x1:301;
        server x.x.x.x2:301;
        }
       server {
                listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name z.z.z.z;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
        location / {
                auth_basic      "protect ki";
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.user;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://ki;
                }
        }
```

Here x IP will always remain same but port will be changed so something like x.x.x.x1:310 , x.x.x.x1:320....etc, so port 301 for client 1 and 310 for client 2 and so on .

Please help

Regards
VG

Comment: Well I guess I need to use multiple upstream with server blocks .

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using maps variables. Add below before the server definition inside the http block

```
map $remote_user $user_site {
   user1    x.x.x.x1;
   user2    x.x.x.x2;
}
```

And change your proxy_pass to

```
proxy_pass http://$user_site;
```

Once authenticated the `$remote_user` will have the name of the user and then `$user_site` will resolve based on the same and you can proxy_pass to it

Answer (score 0):

You need add map section to http context

```
map $remote_user $user {
  default 0;
  user1 1;
  user2 2;
  user3 3;
}
```

and to the server context

```
location / {
  auth_basic      "protect ki";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.user;
  try_files /onexistentn @user;
}

location @user {

    internal;

    if ($user = '1') {
      proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x1:310;
      break;
    }

    if ($user = '2') {
      proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x1:320;
      break;
    }

    if ($user = '3') {
      proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x1:330
      break;
    }

    if ($user = '0') {
      proxy_pass http://ki;
      break;
    }

}
```